# List initialization (aka uniform initialization) and initializer_list?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

Why does the following code give different output?

```
std::vector<int> v{12};
std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
```

```
std::vector<int> v(12);
std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
```

What if I list-initialize an object which has a ctor accepting an initializer_list as parameter?

And how can I call `std::vector::vector(size_t)` with list-initialization?

Comment: A brace-enclosed list of values will always result in the`std::initializer_list` constructor being called, if there is such a constructor (which there is for `std::vector<T>`).

Comment: You may also want to read more about [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization), and the different forms of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List-initialization prefers constructors with a `std::initializer_list` argument. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

> The effects of list-initialization of an object of type T are:
>
> [...cases that do not apply here ...]
>
> - Otherwise, the constructors of T are considered, in two phases:
>
>   - All constructors that take std::initializer_list as the only argument, or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have
>     default values, are examined, and matched by overload resolution
>     against a single argument of type std::initializer_list
>   - If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments
>     that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the
>     restriction that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed. If this
>     stage produces an explicit constructor as the best match for a
>     copy-list-initialization, compilation fails (note, in simple
>     copy-initialization, explicit constructors are not considered at all).

While direct initialization does not prefer the initializer_list constructor. It calls the constructor that takes the size as argument.

And from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector:

> Note that the presence of list-initializing constructor (10) means
> list initialization and direct initialization do different things:
>
> ```
> std::vector<int> b{3}; // creates a 1-element vector holding {3}
> std::vector<int> a(3); // creates a 3-element vector holding {0, 0, 0}
> std::vector<int> d{1, 2}; // creates a 2-element vector holding {1, 2}
> std::vector<int> c(1, 2); // creates a 1-element vector holding {2}
> ```

---

> And how can I call std::vector::vector(size_t) with list-initialization?

As explained above, the presence of the `std::initializer_list` constructor prevents you from calling the other constructor via list-initialization.